# Хаотичное движение анимированной точки в окне

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

По экрану движется точка. Нужно сделать следующее:

1) Движение должно происходить не по всему экрану, а в указанной области (в данном случае в #box;
2) Точка анимируется при помощи animation, но при его включении точка перестаёт хаотично двигаться по экрану, а остаётся почему-то на месте.

```js
setInterval (function(){
  var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
  var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
  var box = document.getElementById('box');
  var dot = document.getElementById('dot');
  //dot.style.animation = 'flash 1s linear infinite';
  dot.style.left = rand1 + 'px';
  dot.style.top = rand2 + 'px';
},1000)
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#box {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
  
  @keyframes flash {
    0% {width: 2px; height: 2px; top: 100px; left: 100px;}
    10% {width: 3px; height: 3px; top: 99px; left: 99px;}
    20% {width: 4px; height: 4px; top: 99px; left: 99px;}
    30% {width: 5px; height: 5px; top: 98px; left: 98px;}
    40% {width: 6px; height: 6px; top: 98px; left: 98px;}
    50% {width: 7px; height: 7px; top: 97px; left: 97px;}
    60% {width: 8px; height: 8px; top: 97px; left: 97px; box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 1px #998200, -1px -1px 3px #998200;}
    70% {width: 8px; height: 8px; top: 96px; left: 96px; box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 1px #998200, -2px -2px 3px #998200;}
    80% {width: 8px; height: 8px; top: 96px; left: 96px; box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px 1px #998200, -3px -3px 4px #998200;}
    90% {width: 8px; height: 8px; top: 95px; left: 95px}
    100% {width: 8px; height: 8px; top: 95px; left: 95px;}
  }
  #dot {
    width: 2px;
    height: 2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #ffd700;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 20px;
    opacity: .9;
    //animation: flash 1s linear infinite;
  }
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="dot"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Раз координаты меняются через JS,то нет смысла менять их через css анимацию. Плавность перехода можно задать при помощи transition.

```js
setInterval (function(){
  var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
  var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
  var box = document.getElementById('box');
  var dot = document.getElementById('dot');
  //dot.style.animation = 'flash 1s linear infinite';
  if(rand1 >= box.clientWidth){
    rand1 = box.clientWidth - 10
  }
  if(rand2 >= box.clientHeight){
    rand2 = box.clientHeight - 10
  }
  dot.style.left = rand1 + 'px';
  dot.style.top = rand2 + 'px';
},1000)
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#box {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
  
  @keyframes anim {
    0% {width: 2px; height: 2px; background-color:red;}
    10% {width: 3px; height: 3px; background-color:green;}
    20% {width: 4px; height: 4px; background-color:blue;}
    30% {width: 5px; height: 5px; background-color:yellow;}
    40% {width: 6px; height: 6px; background-color:brown;}
    50% {width: 7px; height: 7px; background-color:white;}
    60% {width: 8px; height: 8px; box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 1px #998200, -1px -1px 3px #998200;}
    70% {width: 8px; height: 8px; box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 1px #998200, -2px -2px 3px #998200;}
    80% {width: 8px; height: 8px; box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px 1px #998200, -3px -3px 4px #998200;}
    90% {width: 8px; height: 8px; background-color:green;}
    100% {width: 8px; height: 8px; background-color:red;}
  }
  #dot {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 20px;        
    transition:top 1s, left 1s;
    animation: anim 1s steps(1) infinite;
  }
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="dot"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто скрипт "залипает" на animation, возможно стоит использовать JS animate для получения нужного результата.